Could not load file or assembly 'System.IO.Compression.ZipFile
In my published .Net Core 6 application I get an error, when I call a ZipArchive method.
When I richtclick on Project > Dependencies > Frameworks > Microsoft.NETCore.App > System.IO.Compression.ZipFile > Find Dependent Code, the "ExtractToFile" method is marked by Visual Studio.
The code which is called, looks like this:
using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(stream, ZipArchiveMode.Read))
{
    foreach (var entry in zipArchive.Entries)
    {
        entry.ExtractToFile("SomePath");
    }
}

My publish settings are as followed:

When the mentioned code is called I get this error:

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.IO.Compression.ZipFile, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'System.IO.Compression.ZipFile, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'

The folder, containing the published exe, contains the missing System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.dll, with the following properties.

Is the problem that my app is looking for the 6.0.0 version, but I have a higher one? How can I fix this issue inside my app?
EDIT:
Add more information to the code description.
EDIT:
My csproj file



do you have System.IO.Compression.ZipFile installed via nugget? Maybe post csproj as reference

Not manually, its contained inside my Micorosoft.NETCore.App framework, if thats what you mean?

have you tried installing it via nugget manually? Sometimes it might help.

Yes, although the highest available version is only 4.3 and 8 years old :/

Based on the description here, I tried using your question method directly in .net6 and it worked out of the box. Could you try unloading all Nuget references to System.IO.Compression.ZipFile in your solution and see if that helps? When I publish the application and the dll is present in the path. image

In my path the dll is also present, the app just cant find it.

Is it possible that it's a compatibility issue with your project's target framework or other packages? Have you tried testing the new project using just the System.IO.Compression.ZipFile dll? If the problem persists in a new project, could you share simple sample code and steps that can reproduce the problem?
